# jQuery Autocomplete with Categories and ColdFusion

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I need to generate an autocomplete with categories based upon a ColdFusion query. Here is my query:

```
<cfquery name = "GetEvents" datasource = "tcc">
SELECT '{ label: "' + cE_Title + '", category: "Tournaments" }' as cE_Title
,'{ label: "' + cE_Location + '", category: "Locations" }' as cE_Location
FROM CourseEvents
```

Then I put each record into a list, append the lists, and turn the list into an array:

```
<cfset myList = ValueList(GetEvents.cE_Title)>
<cfset myList2 = ValueList(GetEvents.cE_Location)>
<cfset myListApp = ListAppend(myList,myList2)>
<cfset myArrayList = ListToArray(myListApp)>
```

And here is my script:

```
<script>
 $.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
_enderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
  var that = this,
    currentCategory = "";
  $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
    if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
      ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
      currentCategory = item.category;
    }
    that._renderItemData( ul, item );
  });
}
});
</script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    <cfoutput>
       var #toScript(myArrayList, "jsVar")#;
    </cfoutput>
    var availableTags = jsVar;

    $( "#EventSearch" ).catcomplete({
     delay: 0,
     source: availableTags
    });
  });
</script>
```

The results should appear like this:

```
Tournaments
 2nd Annual March Madness Scramble
 River Run Golf Classic

Locations
 Trump International Golf Club
 Stoneybrook Golf and Country Club
```

However, they are appearing like this:

```
{ label: "2nd Annual March Madness Scramble"
category: "Tournaments" }
{ label: "River Run Golf Classic"
category: "Tournaments" }
{ label: "Trump International Golf Club"
category: "Locations" }
{ label: "Stoneybrook Golf and Country Club"
category: "Locations" }
```

Here is a demo: http://www.thecoursecaddy.com/c/sandbox/golfevents.cfm

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *What* is not working? What is it doing? What errors are you receiving?

Comment: Any particular reason you are rejecting the autocomplete attribute of cfinput?

Comment: phantom42 - I am not getting any errors, it is displaying incorrectly. The suggestions appear like this: 1st option is:
    { label: "2nd Annual Breakthrough Tournament"
2nd option is 
    category: "Tournaments" }

Comment: Dan - No particular reason. Can cfinput autocomplete show categories for the suggestions?

Comment: I've never used cfinput autocomplete for real, but I did it once to prove to myself that I could do it.  One thing I thought of after I submtitted the comment though, is that you can only use cfinput if you use cfform and a lot of people choose not to use cfform for various reasons.

Comment: Are you saying you're seeing the raw JSON instead of the parsed results?

Comment: Ben - Yes, it is showing the raw JSON. and the comma within each label/category causes it to become a new line item of the list.

Comment: When you viw source, how does it look? Can we see this online?

Comment: Raymond - You can view this online here:
http://www.thecoursecaddy.com/c/sandbox/golfevents.cfm
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think the `var #toScript(myArrayList, "jsVar")#;` call is messing things up. If you look at the view source, it is not passing the JSON as a string, but as an array of strings. Instead of building the JSON yourself, try `serializeJSON`. Though you may need to tweak things to get the structure you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to do it.  [See demo here](http://www.thecoursecaddy.com/c/sandbox/golfevents.cfm).

Thanks to everyone for their help.

```
<!--- Get List of Events --->
<cfquery name = "GetEvents" datasource = "tcc">
SELECT cE_Title, cE_Location
FROM CourseEvents
</cfquery>

<cfset dataset = [] />

<cfloop query="GetEvents">
 <cfset record = {} />
 <cfset record['label'] = GetEvents.cE_Title />
 <cfset record['category'] = "Tournaments" />
 <cfset ArrayAppend(dataset, record) />
</cfloop>

<cfloop query="GetEvents">
 <cfset record = {} />
 <cfset record['label'] = GetEvents.cE_Location />
 <cfset record['category'] = "Locations" />
 <cfset ArrayAppend(dataset, record) />
</cfloop>

<style>
.ui-autocomplete-category {
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: .2em .4em;
 margin: .8em 0 .2em;
 line-height: 1.5;
 font-size:13px;
}
.ui-menu-item a {
 font-size:11px;
}
</style>
<script>
 $.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
 _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
  var that = this,
    currentCategory = "";
  $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
    if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
      ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
      currentCategory = item.category;
    }
    that._renderItemData( ul, item );
  });
 }
});
</script>
<script>
 $(function() {
  <cfoutput>
     var jsVar = #SerializeJSON(dataset)#;
  </cfoutput>
  var availableTags = jsVar;

  $( "#EventSearch" ).catcomplete({
   delay: 0,
   source: availableTags
  });
});
</script>

<body>
 <cfform action="#cgi.script_name#" method="post">
  <cfinput type="text" id="EventSearch" name="EventSearch">
 </cfform>
</body>
```